# Message in script never gets passed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, message

I have been trying to get the following code that I got from the Facebook Developer site to work properly from a Lotus Domino application:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Great Website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
  </script>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:####################, cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });

     FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
        message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
  </script>
 </body>
```

The popup opens (only from Firefox, not from IE) but the message text never gets passed. Any ideas why? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The message field has been deprecated.  The user must enter their own message into that box.  The documentation is [wrong](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/328210420557109?browse=search_4f456a8c3758f1956820723).

Comment: Great!!! Is there no way for me to pre-populate a message that the user can just click Share and be done with it?

Comment: Technically you can prompt for publish_stream extended permissions and  then publish to their stream directly without their intervention but the way you are doing it is preferred.

Comment: Is there anyway you can provide me with the code to do this? A core function of my new site is to assist users by posting information to their facebook page. Unfortunately, this is not a forte of mine. Thanks!!!

Comment: See the 4th example on the [FB.api documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/)

Comment: I copied that code and placed it on my form. But what do I need to get the fb.api to work>

Comment: To get the API to work, see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ the examples on FB.init to set it up.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'll check that out . . . may be back to bother you again.

Comment: So here's where I am now . . . I placed the following code, which is getting executed however the alert with "error occurred" comes up. Do I need to request the publish_stream permission as well? If so, I cannot figure out how to add that to my code.

Comment: <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
</SCRIPT>

Comment: <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
   var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
   FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
     if (!response || response.error) {
       alert('Error occured');
     } else {
       alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
     }
})
</SCRIPT>